# Wordpress site is not loading properly ( showing a min-page)

Tags: themes, errors, performance, responsive

I hope you are doing well,

yesterday I was adding new products, deleting some of the categories, and uploading photos, and then I checked my changes but suddenly the website was not loading properly as it supposed to be
here is the screenshot of the home page
[image: 1]

And that's my website link:

https://www.darato-iq.com/

please could you please help what is going on?

Comment: The site looks OK to me now. When it was going wrong I'd guess there was an error in the browser console or server logs, that it would have been useful to include in the question.